# Template builder Error while executing - Impersonation

Tags: 2013, template-builder

I am getting the following error in template builder while running a Page and PT.
I am using Tridion 2013 SP1 .

> Access is denied for the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, IEnumerable`1 mappedGroupUris, IEnumerable`1 claimSets)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor()
>      at MetLife.ADD.Marketing.Tridion.Templating.Templating.GenerateSiteMap..ctor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me something is going wrong in the method `MetLife.ADD.Marketing.Tridion.Templating.Templating.GenerateSiteMap` which I would expect to be part of one of the Template Building Blocks in your Page Template.

I think you need to debug its code to see what is going wrong there...

Comment: As a guess, you're trying to impersonate the current user account - in Template Builder that's `Network Service` which cannot login to Tridion (and that is correct behavior). It will probably work when publishing or previewing.